# Does unlocking content alter an NFT?

Tags: nft

I bought an NFT on Rarible that includes unlockable content.  If I unlock the content, will it alter the NFT?  If I sell the NFT will the next owner be able to unlock the content?  In summary, will unlocking the content alter the value in any way (similar to taking a Star Wars figure out of the packaging).

Comment: It depends on the NFT. Check with the creator.